# Angular global error handler prints error.message as the error itself

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, promise

I have a global error handler in my application

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor() {
    console.log( 'error handler constructor');
  }

  handleError(error: any) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

}
```

I throw an error in my service:

```
private sending(data) {
    this.myApi.send({
     type: 'json',
      data: data
    }).then(response => {
      this.onChange.next(response);
    }, httpError => { throw httpError; } );
  }
```

The weird thing is, that in the error handler when I log error.message, the whole error gets printed not just the message part.

The error also has a "promise" and a "rejection" property, and the error status I want is at error.rejection.headers.status.

Thanks.